# Outlook rules moving wrong emails (but works properly when rules are manually applied)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter, rules

I get a lot of automated system alerts each day. I wanted to declutter my inbox, so I setup a number of rules to automatically move these to a "notifications" folder. The rules are generally specified of type: `subject line contains...`.

The trouble is that I am getting a lot of messages incorrectly routed to this "Notifications" folder. I am not sure why, or which rule is driving this. Following a suggestion in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/186078/how-to-determine-what-outlook-rule-was-applied), I have tried moving the messages back to Inbox and manually rerunning the rules through `Rules and Alerts >> Run Rules Now`. **But when I do this manually, the messages don't move!** They stay in the Inbox, just as I intended in the first place!

Can anyone shed light on what might be going on, or what further steps I can take for debugging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that some of my rules were based on the sender. I thought that specifying `FROM <an alias>` would filter only the rules that literally came from that alias. In fact, the rule moves any email from anyone who *is a member* of the alias. [This link](https://superuser.com/questions/885577/exchange-mail-rule-triggering-on-a-from-address-that-is-a-public-group) has some further info, now that I knew what to look for.

(Mind you, I am still not sure why a manual trigger of the same rules did not cause them to move the second time around.)